# Kubernetes Ingress return different certificate with fabric8 than with curl

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, fabric8

Using [fabric8 kubernetes client](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client), I received a different certificate than with curl on the same endpoint.

Specifically, I received the ingress self-signed certificate (CN=Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate) instead of the specified one.

Ingress configuration (result of `kubectl edit ingress`)

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2020-08-07T09:33:18Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app: dummy
    app.kubernetes.io/component: dummy-component
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: dummy-instance
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Dummy
    app.kubernetes.io/name: dummy
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: dummy-sample
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.12.0-SNAPSHOT
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:labels:
          .: {}
          f:app: {}
          f:app.kubernetes.io/component: {}
          f:app.kubernetes.io/instance: {}
          f:app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {}
          f:app.kubernetes.io/name: {}
          f:app.kubernetes.io/part-of: {}
          f:app.kubernetes.io/version: {}
      f:spec:
        f:rules: {}
        f:tls: {}
    manager: okhttp
    operation: Update
    time: "2020-08-07T09:33:18Z"
  - apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:status:
        f:loadBalancer:
          f:ingress: {}
    manager: nginx-ingress-controller
    operation: Update
    time: "2020-08-07T09:33:19Z"
  name: dummy-instance
  namespace: dummy-namespace
  resourceVersion: "1887"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/dummy-namespace/ingresses/dummy-instance
  uid: 2b7839fa-da65-45f3-9f1f-8169cf1325d8
spec:
  rules:
  - host: minikube
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: dummy-instance
          servicePort: 9999
        path: /dummy-instance
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - minikube
    secretName: minikube-tls-3
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 172.17.0.3
```

I cannot see a reason where the Ingress would return a different certificate for the same host, on the same endpoint, with a different client.

My only guess was that the certificate contain in the secret was not compatible (or was having a lower priority on the cipher?) with the fabric8 ClientHello (okhttp3 here), but it's not the case.

I'm running out of debugging idea, so if you have a guess on that, it would be welcome!

Comment: Fabric8 Kubernetes Client just returns deserialized response from Kubernetes API. Do you get same data when you do `kubectl get ingress dummy-instance -v=8`(check json response if it matches)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client doesn't send the SNI extension on the ClientHello.